# TypeORM - Many-to-Many where clause on join table

Tags: typeorm

I'm using `Typeorm@0.2.5` with MySql driver.
I have an entity, `MyEntity`, which has a many-to-many relationship with another entity, `RelEntity`. Therefore Typeorm generates a pivot table of the PKs to create the relationship.

My problem comes from the need to find all `MyEntity` using a where clause of `RelEntity.prop = mySearchKey`.

I'm not sure if this is down to me missing some documentation or not fully understanding how to structure this query withing Typeorm.

I believe my SQL statement for this would look something like:

```
SELECT m.* FROM my_entity_table m 
LEFT JOIN my_rel_pivot_table mrp ON mrp.my_entity_id = m.id 
LEFT JOIN rel_entity_table r ON r.id = mrp.rel_entity_id
WHERE r.id = {MY_VALUE_HERE}
```

However, I'm not too sure how to translate this into a Typeorm query.

I have tried:

```
this.entityRepo.find({
    where: {
        rel: myValue
    }
});
```

I have also tried:

```
this.entityRepo.find({
    where: {
        rel: { id: myValue}
    }
});
```

However, I received the following error:
`Unknown column 'MyEntity.myEntityId' in 'where clause'`

Has anyone encountered this issue before, or have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 9):

I've this working for me, between my articles and categories (many-to-many).

To get my **articles** that are from a specific **category**:

```
  this
  .entityRepo
  .createQueryBuilder('article')
  .innerJoin(
       'article.categories', 
       'category', 
       'category.id = :categoryId', 
       { categoryId: XXX }
  ).getMany();
```

XXX is the id of the specific category.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: But how can I in XXX field the column from another table?

Comment: @YoungAlCapone check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72874976/6625548

Answer (score 5):

After asking for help on GitHub, the answer to the following would be to use the QueryBuilder API.

This can be done such as:

```
const myEntities = await this.entityRepo.createQueryBuilder("entity")
    .leftJoin("relEntity", "relEntity.id = :myId", {myId: myValue})
    .getMany()
```

Many thanks to https://github.com/pleerock for helping me with this.

Comment: is there a way to do this with repo.find({where: {}, relations: []}) syntax in the current version of TypeORM?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is an opened PR for this. I'm looking forward to it. (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2707)

Answer (score 0):

### Many-to-many relations querying

I faced a task, where I needed to do a query for an intermediate table in a many-to-many relationship.

We use a custom soft-delete model, so we needed a way to drop soft-deleted links in an intermediate table.

Basically, what we did, we wrote an extra condition referencing intermediate table name, that is formed like `<left-join-alias>_<right-join-alias>` and querying there a raw field name as it is in the DB. Here it is `STATE_CODE`.

```js
const myEntities = await this.entityRepo
  .createQueryBuilder('entity')
  .leftJoin('entity.manyToManyRel', '"entity_manyToManyRel"."STATE_CODE" != :deleted', {
    deleted: 'D'
  })
  .getMany()
```

### Referencing another table value in a condition

If you want to make a query by another table value, you can do it by referencing its alias and field, if it is an entity table, or by using raw column names, if it is something hidden, like with a many-to-many relationships column.

```js
const myEntities = await this.entityRepo
  .createQueryBuilder('entity')
  .leftJoin('entity.country', 'country')
  .leftJoin('entity.articles', 'articles', 'articles.language = country.language')
  .getMany()
```